# angular directory structure not getting created in IntelliJ

Tags: angularjs, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am following steps in IntelliJ to support Angular.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/using-angular.html#install_angular_cli

In `Generating an Angular application stub using Angular CLI` section, I have to specify some `package_name` for `Angular CLI` field while setting up the project. What should be the value of `package_name`? I keep getting the following message but the angular directory structure doesn't get created.

**"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\bin\ng new angularIntelliJ8 --dir=.
As a forewarning, we are moving the CLI npm package to "@angular/cli" with the next release,
which will only support Node 6.9 and greater. This package will be officially deprecated
shortly after.
To disable this warning use "ng set --global warnings.packageDeprecation=false".
Directory '.' already exists.
Done**

I have specified the path as `C:\Users\Manu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli`

I notice that if I run `ng new angularIntelliJ8` on cmd then the angular directory structure gets created. But doing `where ng` shows the following path for `ng`

```
>where ng
C:\..\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng
C:\..\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.cmd
```

If I use above paths in Angular CLI, I get error that IntelliJ couldn't find bin/ng

Also, if I run '"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Users\Manu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\bin\ng new angularIntelliJ10' on cmd terminal manually (without --dir=.), the structure gets created.

Am I specifying wrong path for `Angular CLI`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update angular-cli to the most recent version (see [Updating Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli) for instructions). Both the package name/location and CLI interface have changed since beta 28, and IDEA 2017.1.* only supports new cli versions.

Once you have a new cli package installed, specify `C:\Users\Manu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli` as a package name in **New Project** wizard